# How do I send an Intent from my Android phone to a paired Google Glass

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass, wear-os

I want to create an intent on the phone and use it to start a service on Glass. Or Send an intent from the phone to Glass, catch it using a BroadcastReceiver and have the BC start the service. But I can't see a way of getting the intent off the phone.

The devices are paired correctly.

SMS received on my phone shows on Glass.

When I created a BroadcastReceiver on Glass to try to catch the SMS received intent, it was never called. So it looks likes the SMS notification is getting to Glass by some alternate mechanism.

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

NB I can't even seem to get a notification created on the phone to appear on Glass. I constructed the notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder` and used the WearableExtender to make it visible to wearables (it showed on my paired LG G), but not on Glass.

```
.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setContentIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_alert))
```

Any ideas on how to send an Intent to a paired wearable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Google Glass will be [getting Android Wear compatibility](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-wear-notifications-are-coming-google-glass), it does not yet have that functionality and therefore does not mirror notifications.

As of right now, there is no Google provided mechanism to send information directly from a device to a connected Google Glass, although there are some [unofficial libraries](https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/GoogleGlassBlutooth).